# Android - add a button to a ListView programatically

Tags: android, button

I am having listview in linear layout, where I need to programatically add button. I have tried several tutiorials and noone was sufficient enoughm, simply it wasn't working. Do you know of some solution?

Edit: I just want to have one button added programatically and my listview (no button in listview). I am not able to add button in my activity programatically.

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/uss"
/>   
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

/>
```

Comment: Where in your ListView do you need to add the Button?  Do you need to add a button to each row of the ListView?  Your layout xml would be helpful as well.

Comment: Do you need to put the button in each of the ListView's rows?

Comment: No, one button and then listview

Comment: OK - is the button ABOVE the ListView or is it at the first row of the ListView.

Comment: Please post your layout xml files.

Comment: Edited - so into LinearLayout, there should go button programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to implement a custom adapter.  You'd add your button to the ListView's rows within the getView() method.  That's going to look something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v;
    if (convertView == null)
        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    else
        v = convertView;

    if(position == 0){
        Button button = new Button();
        v.add( button );    
    }

   return v;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Per the asker's answers to my questions in the coments, the above solution will put the button in the first column of the ListView.

If what you're trying to do is position the button ABOVE the listview so that it does not scroll, then I would put another LinearLayout in your existing Layout that just contains the TextView (id-uss).  That way you can add your button to the end of that LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add button to each row of listview,then you need to go for custom adapter which uses your custom list item xml file,you specified.

and if you need just one button below your listview,you need to get the linear layout where you have added the listview in xml file,and you can add your button to it using `mLinearLayout.add(mButton);`